# separting outlook subject line into columns

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the below code that I am trying to modify to split a subject line into to six columns to view in Excel.

```
Sub subject2excel()
On Error Resume Next
Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
Set mynamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
Set myfolder = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set xlobj = CreateObject("excel.application.14")
xlobj.Visible = True
xlobj.Workbooks.Add
'Set Heading
xlobj.Range("a" & 1).Value = "From"
xlobj.Range("b" & 1).Value = "Subject"

For i = 1 To myfolder.Items.Count
Set myitem = myfolder.Items(i)
msgtext = myitem.Body

xlobj.Range("a" & i + 1).Value = myitem.Sender
xlobj.Range("b" & i + 1).Value = myitem.Subject


Next
End Sub
```

My data is in the below format

```
SLWP Moncton | Cable Service Eng. | 21-Jul-15 | Shift End: 0:00 | Leave Time: entire day | SLWP (Unpaid)
```

So in total 7 columns I plan to leave is below.

Sender
Location
LOB
Date
Shift End Time
Shift Leave Time
Leave Type

In it's current state as you can see it only produces two columns and I do not know how to break the subject line apart.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue

```
Sub subject2excel() 

Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder 
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem 
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace 
Dim xlApp As Object 
Dim xlWB As Object 
Dim i As Long 
Dim j As Long 
Dim vSubject As Variant 


On Error Resume Next 
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 
If Err <> 0 Then 
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
End If 
On Error GoTo 0 'err_Handler
xlApp.Visible = True 
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add 
 'Set Heading
With xlWB.Sheets(1) 
    .Range("A" & 1).Value = "Sender" 
    .Range("B" & 1).Value = "Location" 
    .Range("C" & 1).Value = "LOB" 
    .Range("D" & 1).Value = "Date" 
    .Range("E" & 1).Value = "Shift End Time" 
    .Range("F" & 1).Value = "Requested Leave Time" 
    .Range("G" & 1).Value = "Paid/Unpaid" 
End With 
 'Fill sheet
Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI") 
Set olFolder = olNS.PickFolder 
For i = 1 To olFolder.Items.Count 
    Set olItem = olFolder.Items(i) 
    If InStr(1, olItem.Subject, "|") > 0 Then 
        vSubject = Split(olItem.Subject, "|") 
        With xlWB.Sheets(1) 
            .Range("A" & i + 1).Value = olItem.Sender 
            .Range("B" & i + 1).Value = vSubject(0) 
            .Range("C" & i + 1).Value = vSubject(1) 
            .Range("D" & i + 1).Value = vSubject(2) 
            .Range("E" & i + 1).Value = Trim(Mid(vSubject(3), InStr(1, vSubject(3), Chr(58)) + 1)) 
            .Range("F" & i + 1).Value = Trim(Mid(vSubject(4), InStr(1, vSubject(4), Chr(58)) + 1)) 
            .Range("F" & i + 1).HorizontalAlignment = -4152 'align right
            .Range("G" & i + 1).Value = Replace(Trim(Mid(vSubject(5), InStrRev(vSubject(5), Chr(40)) + 1)), Chr(41), "") 
        End With 
    End If 
Next i 
xlWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Autofit 
exitRoutine: 
Set olFolder = Nothing 
Set xlApp = Nothing 
Set xlWB = Nothing 
Set olItem = Nothing 
lbl_Exit: 
Exit Sub 
err_Handler: 
GoTo lbl_Exit 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Split.

```
Sub subject2excel()

Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myFolder As folder
Dim xlobj As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim myitem As Object

Dim Words() As String

'On Error Resume Next
Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
'Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
Set myFolder = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.currentFolder
Set xlobj = CreateObject("excel.application.14")

xlobj.Visible = True
xlobj.Workbooks.Add

'Set Heading
xlobj.Range("a" & 1).Value = "From"
xlobj.Range("b" & 1).Value = "Subject"

For i = 1 To myFolder.Items.count

    Set myitem = myFolder.Items(i)

    If TypeOf myitem Is MailItem Then
        'msgText = myitem.body

        xlobj.Range("a" & i + 1).Value = myitem.Sender
        'xlobj.Range("b" & i + 1).Value = myitem.Subject

        Words = Split(myitem.Subject, " | ")

        For j = 0 To UBound(Words)
            Debug.Print Words(j)
        Next j

    End If

Next i

exitRoutine:
    Set myOlApp = Nothing
    Set myFolder = Nothing
    Set xlobj = Nothing
    Set myitem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply niton, however when I tried the code the only results I am getting is the sender's information.  Under Subject there is nothing.